# Why is there an "implication" rather than and "and" in this definition of the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic, frechet-derivative

I am readig Pugh's Analysis book:

> **Definition**
>
> Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be given where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The function $f$ is differentiable a $p \in U$ with derivative $(Df)_p = T$ if $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation and $f(p+v) = f(p)+T(v)+R(v) \implies \lim_{|v| \to 0} \dfrac {R(v)}{|v|}=0$.

Partly due to the missing quantifiers, I'm having trouble understanding why there is a "$\implies$" there rather than a "$\wedge$". Isn't it more natural to say

"T is the derivative if we can write $f(p+v) = f(p)+T(v)+R(v)$ AND $\lim_{|v| \to 0} \dfrac {R(v)}{|v|}=0$"?

I'm having trouble seeing what the impact of changing these would be.

Comment: It would probably be clearer to write "...is a linear transformation and $\lim_{|v| \to 0} R(V)/|v| = 0$, where $R(v) = f(p+v) - f(p) - T(v)$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for the reply. I've seen that definition in another book as well. I'm having trouble understanding how that definition related to Pugh's; is it equivalent to the definition with $\implies$? Or to the one with $\wedge$? Or is the one with $\wedge$ nonsense? I have a vague feeling that $\implies$ and $\wedge$ won't matter because the derivative is unique, but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author means

$$\forall R \left((\forall v ~ f(p+v) = f(p) + T(v) + R(v)) \implies \lim_{|v| \to 0} \frac{R(v)}{|v|} = 0\right)$$

which is taking advantage of how only one function for $R$ satisfies the condition.  You are maybe thinking something like

$$ \bigg(R = v \mapsto f(p + v) - f(p) - T(v)\bigg) \land \bigg(\lim_{|v| \to 0} \frac{R(v)}{|v|} = 0\bigg)$$

The problem with the second equation is that it isn't defining $R$ as $v \mapsto f(p + v) - f(p) - T(v)$, it is saying 'if' $R$ is defined as such.  Alternatively,

$$\begin{cases} \text{define } R \text{ as } v \mapsto f(p + v) - f(p) - T(v) \\
\lim_{|v| \to 0} \frac{R(v)}{|v|} = 0 \end{cases}$$

is an option, in that case sort of using 'and' in the casual sequential sense, like 'crack the egg and put the egg in the bowl and beat the egg and pour the egg into the pan...'.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I understand it but it seems really really weird; your third approach seems the most natural and I don't see anybody would use anything else; will have to digest it more.

Comment: It seems like the author is using the first route just so he can avoid making a definition for $R$ before the actual definition of differentiability?

Comment: Yeah, it is odd he didn't bother directly using a definition, and also didn't just write $$\lim_{|v| \to 0} \frac{f(p + v) - f(p) - T(v)}{|v|} = 0$$

Comment: If I could ask you another thing; can I formulate it like this?  $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $p$ if $\exists T \exists R \forall v : \left( \dfrac{}{} f(p+v) = f(p)+T(v)+R(v) \right) \wedge \left( \lim_{v \to 0} \dfrac {|R(v)|}{|v|} = 0 \right) $?

Comment: @Ovi You should take the $\exists T$ off because $T$ is being defined so it must be left free in the definition, but otherwise yes that is fine.  It is a common trick when encoding things in First Order Logic to convert $a = f(g(b))$ to $\exists y~(a = f(y) \land y = g(b))$

Comment: Ah okay thanks; but do you think I should also place the $\forall v$ inside the LHS of the conjugation? I'm worried it might mess with the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of the limit, i.e. it may become $\forall v \forall \epsilon \exists \delta ...$?

Comment: @Ovi Oh yeah for sure it should be $\cdots (\forall v : ( \cdots)) \implies \cdots$.  But if you want to keep the quantifiers on the outside you can use the identity $$\bigg((\forall v : Pv) \implies Q\bigg) \equiv \bigg(\exists v : (Pv \implies Q)\bigg)$$ but you risk making things correct but unintelligible if you do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see I need to learn a little bit more logic...

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for Pugh, but your construction

> T is the derivative if we can write $f(p+v) = f(p)+T(v)+R(v)$ AND $\lim_{|v| \to 0} \dfrac {R(v)}{|v|}=0$

is awkward because neither the left nor the right side of the "AND" is a property of $T$ that needs checking. The left side is always true; you *can* always do that. And the right side makes no sense unless $R$ is constrained.

Look at it this way, would you write the following?

> T is the derivative if $\lim_{|v| \to 0} \dfrac {R(v)}{|v|}=0$ AND we can write $f(p+v) = f(p)+T(v)+R(v)$

Comment: Thank you for the response!